# Monotouch / Monodroid to desktop application

Tags: xamarin.ios, desktop-application, xamarin.android

I'm currently developping mobile app with Monotouch (and Monodroid) and I try to find a way to export my app as a MAC OSX destop appplication/software AND Windows Application/software.

Does anyone knows how to do it ? 
Can I build a compatible windows .exe application ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use MonoTouch and Mono for Android projects for desktop applications directly. If you separate your logic code from user interface one, you can create your desktop project (for Windows, Mac and Linux) and use that logic code.
MonoTouch and Mono for Android use a subset of the .Net framework (Mono) assemblies (http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/about/assemblies and http://docs.xamarin.com/android/about/assemblies), so the code written with those assemblies can be used to create apps with Mono for Mac, Mono for Linux, Mono for Windows and .Net framework itself.

Comment: To expand upon this theme of UI separation, see the MWC app sample. IT doesn't do desktop + mobile, but it does use a common "business" layer across iOS, Android, and WP7 devices: http://blog.xamarin.com/2012/02/24/mwc_2012/ https://github.com/xamarin/mobile-samples/tree/master/MWC